# eliminate first position of tuples from list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this list of tuples:

```
t_s           = [((1, 0, 0), 1), ((1, 0, 1), 1), ((1, 1, 0), 1), ((1, 1, 1), 0)]
```

that I want to turn into:

```
clean_t_s    = [((0, 0), 1), ((0, 1), 1), ((1, 0), 1), ((1, 1), 0)]
```

How can I do this pythonically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this, for example:

```
In [1]: %paste
t_s           = [((1, 0, 0), 1), ((1, 0, 1), 1), ((1, 1, 0), 1), ((1, 1, 1), 0)]

## -- End pasted text --

In [2]: [(a[1:], b) for a, b in t_s]
Out[2]: [((0, 0), 1), ((0, 1), 1), ((1, 0), 1), ((1, 1), 0)]
```